# Autofac with WCF4 Self Hosted Service (no .svc)

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

Is it necessary to specify the service implementation type and host factory for a self-hosted service with no .svc? When I try to run the console app below I'm getting an error that there's no default constructor, so it seems my container registrations aren't being used. What am I missing?

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(c => new GenericRepository()).As<IRepository>();
builder.Register(c => new BusinesLogic(c.Resolve<IRepository>())).As<IBusinesLogic>();
builder.Register(c => new MyService(c.Resolve<IBusinesLogic>())).As<IMyService>();

using (IContainer container = builder.Build())
{
    var address = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8523/MyService");
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), address);

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new NetTcpBinding(), string.Empty);
    host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<IMyService>(container);
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = false });
    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Navigate to the following URI to see the service.");
    Console.WriteLine(address);
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    host.Close();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured out what I was missing in a blog post by Alex Meyer-Gleaves. I needed to call ComponentRegistry.TryGetRegistration

https://alexmg.com/posts/self-hosting-wcf-services-with-the-autofac-wcf-integration

Here's my updated code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(c => new GenericRepository()).As<IRepository>();
builder.Register(c => new BusinessLogic(c.Resolve<IRepository>())).As<IBusinessLogic>();
builder.Register(c => new MyService(c.Resolve<IBusinessLogic>())).As<IMyService>();

using (IContainer container = builder.Build())
{
    var address = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8523/MyService");
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), address);

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new NetTcpBinding(), string.Empty);

    IComponentRegistration registration;
    if (!container.ComponentRegistry.TryGetRegistration(new TypedService(typeof(IMyService)), out registration))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The service contract has not been registered in the container.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }

    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior(container, typeof(MyService), registration));
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = false });
    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Navigate to the following URI to see the service.");
    Console.WriteLine(address);
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    host.Close();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```